# Javascript texas holdem database

Tags: javascript, mongodb, database

Im trying to create texas holdem in javascript ( using node and mongodb server sided).

But im currently stuck on how i should structure the database.

here is what i got so far:

```
player1 - player9 = userid
```

means a column called player1 all the way upto player9, that will contain a userid. if none, will be 0

`player 1cash- player 9cash`
 means a column called player1 all the way upto player9, that will contain a number cash on table (in front of user). if none, will be 0

`player 1cards- player 9cards`
 means a column called player1 all the way upto player9, that will contain a two cards on table (in front of user). if none, will be 0

```
maxbet : Number
```

will be the maxbet / max buy in

```
smallblind : userid // contains userid of small blind
bigblind : userid // contains high
blindamount : Number // amount
```

`cards_on_table` : // contains all cards on table

If i proceed on this , it would have 31 columns each game.

How can i make this database interaction better, or change my db structure to something better?

Comment: "How can I make this better" - do you think this one is bad?

Comment: Yes, i feel IT can be done better @SergioTulentsev

Comment: Better in what regard? There is no abstract "better"

Comment: how to store it more effective. @SergioTulentsev

Comment: If you worry about disk usage, WiredTiger's compression will help, without the need to change you schema. When designing a database, one should base the design on __requirements__: what the app should be able to do, with what queries can we accomplish that, how to make those queries fast without sacrificing too much in other areas? This kind of questions.

Comment: This design of yours, it looks good to me as a starting point. Start working with it, identify problems (if any), return to ask _better_ questions.

Comment: Players are usually a row in a table; not a column.  When ever you start numbering colums (player1, player2, ...) usually that's a sign that you should make a separate table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to impose a relational model in MongoDB (column oriented, which would translate in single value fields, as it is understood from your description), you could better leverage the document oriented architecture of MongoDB that allows you to use objects in your schema:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId("5805d576adf2ac885283779a"),

    // Name of the room
    room_name: 'Hold Them Up',

    // When the room was created
    created_at: ISODate("2016-10-18T08:04:17.611Z"),

    // The uptime of the room in seconds or any other unit    
    uptime: 2000,

    // You could organize this as an object that contains values for
    // each of the turning phases of the game to allow for better analytics
    current_table_cards: {
        flop: ["A", "B", "C"],
        turn: "D",
        river: "E"
    },

    // You could also keep track of previous table cards
    table_cards_history: [
        {
            flop: ["A", "B", "C"],
            turn: "D",
            river: "E"
        },
        {
            flop: ["E", "D", "C"],
            turn: "B",
            river: "A"
        },
        ...

    ],

    // You could use an array to store the players that are currently playing
    // and save a history of their previous 5 hands for example
    //
    // To track the order of the players, you can either manipulate this array
    // and consider the indices the order of the players, or you could define
    // an order property on the objects inside this array
    players: [
        {
            user_id: ObjectId("5805d576adf2ac8852837791"),
            cash_amount: 3201,
            position: 2,
            win: 1,
            loss: 0,
            current_hand: ["E", "F"],
            hands_history: [
                ["A", "B"],
                ["A", "A"],
                ...
            ]
        },
        {
            user_id: ObjectId("5805d576adf2ac8852837792"),
            cash_amount: 4288,
            position: 1,
            win: 2,
            loss: 1,
            current_hand: ["C", "D"],
            hands_history: [
                ["A", "E"],
                ["B", "B"],
                ...
            ]
        },
        {
            user_id: ObjectId("5805d576adf2ac8852837793"),
            cash_amount: 2531,
            position: 3,
            win: 0,
            loss: 2,
            current_hand: ["A", "B"],
            hands_history: [
                ["D", "D"],
                ["C", "C"],
                ...
            ]
        },
        ...
    ],

    // Blind information
    small_blind: ObjectId("5805d576adf2ac8852837792"),
    big_blind: ObjectId("5805d576adf2ac8852837791"),
    blind_amount: 100
}
```

This is just a starting model for your application that could end up having a lot more fields, depending on the information that you want to track for each room and player.

For example, you might want to track the average betting amount of a player, or maybe set a timer for when the blinds change. However, this is beyond the scope of this question and is a different discussion.

Moreover, as **Sergio Tulentsev** mentioned in his comments, it is very important to optimize your data model based on the information that you need to extract. Thus, based on application requirements, you will have to find a balance between your data model and query access patterns in order to optimize performance.

Comment: what do u mean with flop,turn and river?;)

Comment: The `flop` is the term for the first 3 cards put on the table in a Texas Hold 'Em game, the next card is called the `turn`, the last card is called the `river` :) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texas_hold_%27em

Comment: do you have time to take a chat @Vlad Z. ?

Comment: @maria sure, feel free to invite me to a chatroom